# ansible 2.0.1 environment variables

Tags: linux, environment-variables, ansible

I used ansible 2.0.1 to run some tasks in remote hosts . the problem was that ansible use the variable of my machine not remote machines for example I want to set the PATH . ansible use the PATH of my machine not of the remote host .

Comment: Can you show what you're trying to do right now? Post your playbook and any variables you are trying to set

Comment: my play-book contain only those lines :

---
- name: Set Path for java 
  command: bash -c  "export $JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH"

Answer (score 1):

You can try copying bash script over to remote host and execute it using Ansible.